# How can I keep finding the Max value in an Array and keep incrementing the Max value for a determinate number of times, in a loop?

Tags: javascript

I want to manipulate an `Array` during a loop in such a way that I want to:

**1 -** find current maximum number in the array (would need to keep updating this value during the loop)

**2 -**  `push` this number adding it to an increment

**3 -** Perform number 1 & 2 tasks `x` times, according to my will.

this code can be found 
[here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/numbers-in-between-rendered-by-an-interval-to-diminish-the-array-length-f8red?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

This is what I am trying to do:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    classesArr: [1581620400000, 1581622800000],
    classesComplete: [1581620400000]
  };

  render() {
    let test = (array, duration) => {
      const min = Math.min(...array);
      let newArr = [min];
      for (let i = 0; i < duration; i++) {
        newArr.push(Math.max(newArr) + 60000);
      }
      return newArr;
    };
    console.log(test(this.state.classesArr, 40));

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

this is the result of my `console.log`

````
0: 1581620400000
1: 1581620460000
2: NaN
3: NaN
4: NaN
5: NaN
6: NaN
7: NaN
8: NaN
9: NaN
10: NaN
11: NaN
12: NaN
13: NaN
14: NaN
15: NaN
16: NaN
17: NaN
18: NaN
19: NaN
20: NaN
21: NaN
22: NaN
23: NaN
24: NaN
25: NaN
26: NaN
27: NaN
28: NaN
29: NaN
30: NaN
31: NaN
32: NaN
33: NaN
34: NaN
35: NaN
36: NaN
37: NaN
38: NaN
39: NaN
40: NaN
​```

As you can see ```newArr.push(Math.max(newArr) + 60000)``` is only performed once.

How could I make this work, and have the increment done 40 times
````

Comment: why using Math.max(newArr)? why not use newArr[newArr.length - 1] because your newArr is already going to be sorted. Math.max() won't work on array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

`newArr.push(Math.max.apply(null, newArr)  + 60000);`

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I have never used ```.apply()``` before. I will study about it now. Thanks very much for shedding some light